PHP + Laravel + Nginx App Setup is slow to load
PHP + Laravel Dockerfile :
FROM php:7.3-fpm AS builder

# Clean-up Repo list
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl -sS -o /tmp/icu.tar.gz -L https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/download/release-57-1/icu4c-57_1-src.tgz && tar -zxf /tmp/icu.tar.gz -C /tmp && cd /tmp/icu/source/ && ./configure --prefix=/usr/local && make && make install

# Install common php extension dependencies
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    coreutils \
    libfreetype-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    unzip \
    git

# Enable Apache mod_rewrite for URL rewriting
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Install PHP Extensions
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext/redis; \
    curl -fsSL --ipv4 https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/5.3.2.tar.gz | tar xvz -C "/usr/src/php/ext/redis" --strip 1; \
    docker-php-ext-install redis

RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip && \
    docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gettext && \
    docker-php-ext-install gettext

RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl && \
    docker-php-ext-install intl

RUN docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql && \
    docker-php-ext-install  pdo_mysql

RUN docker-php-ext-configure mysqli && \
    docker-php-ext-install  mysqli && \
    docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

# Copy existing application directory
COPY . /var/www/html

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
    && chmod -R 775 /var/www/app/storage

# Install composer
COPY --from=composer:1.6.3 /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN mkdir -p ~/.ssh && \
    chmod 0700 ~/.ssh && \
    ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org > ~/.ssh/known_hosts

# Copy composer.json to workdir
COPY composer.* ./
# RUN omposer install & Clone private repository
RUN --mount=type=ssh composer install

COPY dotenv/.env.development .env

ARG NODE_VERSION=8.16.2
RUN curl https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz | tar -xz -C /usr/local --strip-components 1
RUN npm install
RUN npm run dev
# Command to start the Artisan server
# CMD ["php", "artisan", "serve", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=8000"]

This service listen at website:8000
Nginx Config :
    # limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=login:10m rate=25r/s;

    # upstream website {
    #     server website:8000;
    # }

    upstream assets {
        server poc.assets.example.com:80;
    }

    upstream drupal {
        server drupal.cms-prod.svc.cluster.local:80;
    }

    server {
        listen         80 default_server;
        server_name    localhost;
        proxy_connect_timeout 30;
        proxy_send_timeout   30;
        proxy_read_timeout   30;
        send_timeout         30;

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types
            application/atom+xml
            application/javascript
            application/json
            application/rss+xml
            application/vnd.ms-fontobject
            application/x-font-ttf
            application/x-web-app-manifest+json
            application/xhtml+xml
            application/xml
            font/opentype
            image/svg+xml
            image/x-icon
            text/css
            text/plain
            text/x-component;


        location / {
             proxy_pass http://website:8000;
        }

        location /images/ {
            proxy_pass http://dev.example.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assets/images/;
            proxy_redirect http://dev.example.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assets/images/ /images/;
        }

        location /toolbox/ {
            proxy_pass http://dev.example.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assets/toolbox/;
            proxy_redirect http://dev.example.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assets/toolbox/ /toolbox/;
        }

        location /downloads/ {
            proxy_pass http://dev.example.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assets/downloads/;
            proxy_redirect http://dev.example.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assets/downloads/ /downloads/;
        }

        location /sites/default/files/ {
            proxy_pass http://drupal/sites/default/files/;
            proxy_redirect http://drupal/sites/default/files/ /sites/default/files/;
        }

        location /nginx_status {
              stub_status on;
              allow all;
        }

    }

All requests for dev.example.com hits nginx first and requests are forwarded to PHP + Laravel App. This setup is deployed Kubernetes.
But this Webpage is taking too long to load in browser.

How log does it takes from start of request until first line of PHP executed?
